# adb shell copy all currently directory to new folder

Tags: java, android, shell, command, adb

I am trying to copy all the content of the currently folder onto another hidden folder:

I want all the content from folderA onto the Folder B

```
--sdcard
- FoldeA 
- .FolderB >>This is a hidden folder

shell../mnt/sdcard $ cp -a FolderA/. .FolderB >Do not work

shell../mnt/sdcard $ cp FolderA/. .FolderB >Do not work

shell../mnt/sdcard $ cp /FolderA/. /.FolderB/ >Do not work

shell../mnt/sdcard/FolderA $ cp . /.FolderB/ >Do not work
```

Any suggestion please, thank you

Comment: have you tried `cp -r` ?

Comment: The `cp` command is not available in Android shell unfortunately. With files, you usually have to use `cat`.

Answer (score 2):

Basic unix command for copying all files from source to destination-

> adb shell cp /data/local/a/* /data/local/b/

Comment: Unfortunately, `cp` isn't included in Android.

Comment: is there `busybox` isntalled in your android device ? just try `busybox cp `.

Answer (score 1):

use cp command with -r

> cp -r /FolderA/* /FolderB

Answer (score 0):

adb pull command, copy the complete directory into destination folder

```
adb pull /data/local/a /data/local/b/
```